De tres section el navegador Firefox en la tercera section me distribuye el texto en forma diferente creando una línea de texto en blanco intermedia?
En el código HTML tengo tres sections idénticas de tres productos, con idéntico CSS dentro de @media para pantalla de de 760 x 1024, pero el navegador Firefox en la tercera section, y a pesar que el CSS es el mismo para las tres, me efectúa una distribución diferente del texto.
El resultado del formato del texto es:

De la primera section:
Con lanas seleccionadas y diseño para
satisfacer sus necesidades, sus sueños.
De la segunda section:
Con lanas seleccionadas y diseño para
satisfacer sus necesidades, sus sueños.
De la tercera section:
Con lanas seleccionadas y diseño para
satisfacer sus necesidades, sus
sueños."

Donde "sueños queda fuera del border.
No encuentro la forma de eliminar de dicho formato la línea vacía para que quede igual que las dos de más arriba.
HTML:
 <!-- Heading -->
  

     <section id="section1" class="page-section clearfix">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="intro" style= "margin-left: 500px">
            <img id="img1" class="intro-img img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-5" src="Tienda/Imgs/Lana 12.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="intro-text left-0 text-center bg-faded p-10 rounded">
              <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                  <br><br>
                <span id="artesanal1" class="section-heading-upper">Artesanal</span>
                  <br>
                <span class="section-heading-lower">Hecho con agujas</span>
              </h2>
              <p class="mb-2">Con lanas   seleccionadas y diseño   para satisfacer sus necesidades, sus sueños.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

  

    <section id="section2" class="page-section clearfix">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="intro" style= "margin-left: 500px"  >
            <img id="img2"  class="intro-img img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-5" " src="Tienda/Imgs/Lana 16.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="intro-text left-0 text-center bg-faded p-10 rounded">
              <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                  <br><br>
                <span id="artesanal2" class="section-heading-upper">Artesanal</span>
                   <br>
                <span class="section-heading-lower">Hecho a mano</span>
              </h2>
              <p id="p2">Con lanas seleccionadas y diseño para satisfacer sus necesidades, sus sueños.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    <section id="section3" class="page-section clearfix">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro" style= "margin-left: 500px"  >
        <img id="img3"  class="intro-img img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-5" src="Tienda/Imgs/Lana 24.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="intro-text left-0 text-center bg-faded p-10 rounded">
          <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
              <br><br>
            <span id="artesanal3" class="section-heading-upper">Artesanal</span>
               <br>
            <span class="section-heading-lower">Punto por punto</span>
          </h2>
          <p id="p3">Con lanas y diseños originales para satisfacer sus necesidades, sus sueños.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

CSS:
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1080px) {
   #section2 {
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
   }
      #section3 {
      position: relative;
      top: 99px;
   }
   .intro .intro-img {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: relative;
       left: -50px;
       top: 50px;
   }
    .intro .intro-text {
       width: 155%;
       height: 270px;
       margin-top: -100px;
       background-color: white;
       position: relative;
       left: -470px;
       top: 55px;
       opacity: .5;
       border: solid 2px black;
    }
    #img2{
       position: relative;
       top: 30px;
    }
    #img3{
       position: relative;
       top: 5px;
    }
    .section-heading{
       position: relative;
    }
    .section-heading .section-heading-upper{
       font-size: 2rem;
       position: relative;
       bottom: 280px;
       left: 30px;
    }
    .section-heading .section-heading-lower{
       font-size: 2rem;
       position: relative;
       bottom: 300px;
       left: 30px;
    }
    #artesanal1{
       height: 299px;
       position: relative;
       top: -230px;
     }
     #artesanal2{
       height: 299px;
        position: relative;
       top: -254px;
     }
     #artesanal3{
       height: 299px;
       position: relative;
       top: -278px;
     }
    .mb-2{
       position: relative;
       bottom: 120px;
       top: -110px;
       left: 20px;
       width: 350px;
       height: 90px;
       text-indent: -16em;
       border: solid 2px black;
    }
    #p2{
       position: relative;
       bottom: 120px;
       top: -110px;
       left: 20px;
       width: 350px;
       height: 90px;
       text-indent: -16em;
       border: solid 2px black;
    }
    #p3{
       position: relative;
       bottom: 120px;
       top: -110px;
       left: 20px;
       width: 350px;
       height: 90px;
       text-indent: -16em;
       border: solid 2px black;
    }
}


En el  img de la segunda sección tienes unas comillas dobles de más entre class y src: lg-5" " src="Tie. Asegúrate siempre que tu HTML esté bien formado, pues con HTML mal formado, cada navegador se comportará diferente.

Gracias jachguate.  En este caso al corre3gir no ha habido variación en el comportameinto.-

Traté de reproducir lo que describes y no logro reproducirlo. Sugiero que revises para ver cuál es el código que realmente tiene ese comportamiento o que completes la descripción. No es que trabaje bien, pero no se comporta como dices, así luce el resultado.

Lo ideal es que, como parte de la pregunta, publiques un [mcve].
